# Problemas ao fechar splash screen do RAD (v7.5)

Tags: java, eclipse, java-ee, desempenho

Estou tendo um problema incomum (quem não?), Minha tela de launcher / splash abre, mas ela mantém este estado mesmo depois de eu escolher a área de trabalho e depois do RAD carregar o projeto. Ele só fecha quando eu paro todo o software.
A última mudança que o meu RAD sofreu antes disso começar a acontecer foi a adição de alguns plugins para um projeto que usa Jasper e Crystal.

Eu já tentei usar o parâmetro -clean um milhar de vezes, mas nada mudou.

[update] 
Investigando a causa do problema eu reparei que ao trocar de workspace a loading screen fecha e quando volta, junto com a janela principal da IDE, ela continua lá, mas o windows não a "vê", mais como uma segunda janela do mesmo software; não aparece no alt+tab ou na taskbar mais até eu fechar e abrir o RAD de novo.

obrigada

Comment: Algum código é útil para ajudar a determinar a causa do erro.

Comment: Que tipo de código @mutley? é algum problema de configuração da IDE, não?

Comment: Não tenho certeza. O código iria ajudar a determinar a causa do problema.

Comment: @mutley, só se for o código da IDE haha, brincadeira.